# Cannot import yahoo finance statistics data into Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, yahoo-finance

I am trying to import yahoo finance statistics data for a certain stock into google sheets but the table is not being recognized by the `IMPORTHTML` function.

Here's my formula:
`=INDEX(IMPORTHTML(CONCATENATE("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/",B2,"/key-statistics"),"TABLE",1), 6,2)`

It does pull some data but it's not from the table I am trying to target. Looks like the table I am trying to target is more than just HTML, not sure if that has something to do with it. It's the very first table at the top of the page I am trying to target.
[Appian Stock Stats page in Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/APPN/key-statistics?p=APPN)

How do I import the Price/Sales ratio specifically on that page?

Comment: From your question, unfortunately, I cannot understand about your goal. I apologize for this. Can you provide the output you expect?

Comment: What do you have on cell `B2`?

Comment: B2 is the ticket symbol, in this case it's APPN. Trying to make the formula dynamic based on the Ticker symbol that's referenced.